# Change color for Warning: ENC1003 Changes made in project will not be applied while the application is running

Tags: visual-studio, edit-and-continue

I have Edit and Continue enabled, but every small change I make to my project causes this warning to appear at runtime.

I don't mind the warning per se, but the problematic code shows in the editor with a green squiggly underline. This make it indistinguishable from other warnings. Is it possible to change the test editor style for these warnings?

Another thread suggested changing the style for "Rude Edits", but my Visual Studio is configured to show rude edits with a **purple** underline.

If it's not possible to change the style, is it possible to hide these warnings altogether?

Comment: Looks like squiggles the Font+Colors dialog.  Ought to be "Warning".